# dpkg: error processing package unity-tweak-tool (--configure)

Tags: 14.04, unity, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

when i run apt-get install, apt-get upgrade, apt-get -f install, it always return this :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/333 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package unity-tweak-tool (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 unity-tweak-tool
```

What's wrong? I try all command like apt-get remove, purge, clean and there is no effect and still return error.

[EDIT] i try to reinstall unity tweak tool, but it returns :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/333 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 216695 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../unity-tweak-tool_0.0.6ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
Aborted (core dumped)
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 134
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
Aborted (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/unity-tweak-tool_0.0.6ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 134
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
Aborted (core dumped)
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 134
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/unity-tweak-tool_0.0.6ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-tweak-tool
```

as recommended by the error message. You have probably deleted some of the files manually and broke the package.

Comment: it doesn't work. i was editing my question. see the result.

Comment: It looks like you broke a lot in your system. The easiest way is to re-install the system and never delete system files manually.

Answer (score -1):

you could try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge unity-tweak-tool
sudo -i
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: sudo apt-get purge unity-tweak-tool return : dpkg: error processing package unity-tweak-tool (--purge):  package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal

Comment: Reinstall dpkg sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg and sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: You could try this sudo dkms-reconfigure unity-tweak-tool